# Pros and Cons: having Enum or Class for Message Notification types

Tags: java, oop, architecture

please advise pros and cons of following architectural solutions

NotificationSender that serializes and sends general NotificationMessage

```
class NotificationSender {
  public void send(NotificationMessage message) {
    client.send(serializeToJson(message));    
  }
}

class NotificationMessage<E> {
  E payload;
  NotificationType type;

  public NotificationMessage(payload, type) {
    this.payload = payload;
    this.type = type;
  }
 }

 Enum NotificationType {
   session, invite, etc, 100 more types...
 } 

 NotificationSender.send(
   new NotificationMessage<SessionDTO>(sessionDTO, NotificationType.session)
 );
```

NotificationSender that serializes and sends different NotificationMessage's for each type (SessionNotificationMessages, etc)

```
class NotificationSender {
  public void send(NotificationMessage message) {
    client.send(serializeToJson(message));    
  }
}

abstract class NotificationMessage<E> {
    E payload;
}

class SessionNotificationMessage extends NotificationMessage {
    static final String = "session";

    public NotificationMessage(payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}

class InviteNotificationMessage extends NotificationMessage {
    static final String = "invite";

    public NotificationMessage(payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}

NotificationSender.send(new SessionNotificationMessage(sessionDTO));
NotificationSender.send(new InviteNotificationMessage(inviteDTO));
```

Thank you

Comment: Please tell us the serialization framework and target language that you intend to use, and please add your personal thoughts about pros and cons to your question.

Comment: added some code samples

Answer (score 3):

Use the enum.  Do not create 100 subclasses, unless they have distinct behaviors (that is, they override methods).

An enum with many constants is very cheap in terms of memory and execution.  Having that many classes is not cheap, and certainly will make the API harder for others to use.

An enum is a limited value set:  any variable with an enum type is guaranteed to contain one of the enum constants (or null).

It’s *possible* to accomplish the same thing with subclasses, if the classes are final and/or the constructors are kept package-private, but even then, users of the API will never be completely certain of which values are valid, because there is no way to list all descendants of a class with absolute certainty, due to the way classes are dynamically loaded.

Comment: I agree with @VGR. One additional argument: JSON doesn't know the concept of an instance's class, it's just the key-value pairs. So, with the multi-class approach, parsing JSON back to Java will have a hard time figuring out which class to instantiate.

Comment: What about type safety?
If we accidentaly would mistaken in first example

For instance 
 NotificationSender.send(
   new NotificationMessage<SessionDTO>(sessionDTO, NotificationType.invite)
 );

Comment: @FedorPetryk Well, that’s a more complex problem than what you described in your question.  If only some enum values apply to each DTO type, I’m thinking you shouldn’t have them all in a single enum.  I would create separate enums, like `enum SessionMessageType`.  It’s perfectly fine if some of them duplicate each other’s constant names.